# How to make calculations work inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am workng on a personal project for bookkeeping so you can tell I am having to do some basic math calculations. I am doing this inside a bootstrap modal.

As shown in the image, the Payment Made input needs to update the value inside the Total Paid (Ignoring other calculations). In short, adding any value inside the field should update the Total Paid input field. The issue is that nothing happens. I am building the form using the Formidable forms plugin. Adding the form elsewhere in a wordpress page/post works perfectly but not inside a modal.

My modal code:

```
<div class="container demo">
<div class="text-center">
<p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2[key]">
Add Payment</button></p>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal2[key]" class="modal right fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
<div class="modal-dialogg" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>-->
<h5 id="myModalLabel2" class="modal-title">Add Transaction</h5>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>[formidable id=62 entry_id=[878]]</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The ids of the fields that are not calculating are:

```
#field_nfjwh-i621
#field_w3ywg
#field_fekmf
```

I am a bit new to Js forgive my ignorance but I tried to give it a shot as shown below. Added the code inside `<head></head>`

```
<script>
  var myModal = document.getElementById('myModal2[key]');
  myModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var field1 = document.querySelector('#myModal2[key] #field_nfjwh-i621');
    var field2 = document.querySelector('#myModal2[key] #field_w3ywg');
    var field3 = document.querySelector('#myModal2[key] #field_fekmf');
  });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: The `<script>` code must be placed at the end of `<body>`, not `<head>`, to ensure your DOM is ready before you can start querying.

Comment: Also, check your browser console if there are any error related to js .